# Is 'knowledge' a single concept?

Tags: knowledge

Is 'knowledge' a single concept? Obviously it has a variety of different philosophical definions, JTB, JTB+ etc.. Suppose that I think 'knowledge' must involve a certain form of justification that I lack for some belief: can I nevertheless claim that the belief amounts to knowledge?

Comment: See [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-analysis/#LighKnow):"Some epistemologists have suggested that there may be multiple senses of the term “knowledge”, and that not all of them require all three elements of the tripartite theory of knowledge. For example, some have argued that there is... weak sense of “knowledge”, that requires only true belief... Even among those epistemologists... most typically admit that there is also a stronger sense..., and that it is this stronger sense that is the main target of epistemological theorizing about knowledge."

Comment: maybe reliabalism is the answer i am looking for: some true beliefs are justified more reliably than others, and it's somewhat arbitrary where the cut off is for 'knnowledge'

Comment: That works, but it would mean not that "knowledge" is a mixture of multiple concepts, but rather that it is a [vague concept](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/).

Comment: Yeah @Conifold probably both

Comment: "knowledge is a vague concept" seems crushingly ironic and self-defeating.

Comment: maybe you're right @ScottRowe

Comment: in this instance, i think it would be beneficial to separate out philosophical and everyday ideas of knowledge @Conifold and that this may dissolve many of the issues

Comment: It may resolve some. But this is what the term "lightweight knowledge" intended (see the first link), but people are still debating.

Comment: but you'd asgree, right, that lightweight knowledge is a cognitive phenomena, even if not knowledge @Conifold what about preverbal and intuitive justification of a belief, if they would never work in argument. are these instances of JTB?

Comment: can you start a chat room @Conifold i think there's been another misunderstanding. we haven't broken up